# When do I have access to props in the react class?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-native

I am passing a meteor collection as a prop in one of my components and trying to figure it out when do I actually receive props?

I tried accessing (for e.g. `this.props.userData`) the props in `getInitialState` is says undefined, then I tried accessing it in componentDidMount it says undefined, but in render method it works fine.

Which method before or after `render` can tell me that I have access to props? I want to initialize the state with the values props will have.

for example in the code below I get an error saying that userData is undefined.

```
getInitialState(){
    return{
        firstName : this.props.userData.firstName
    }
}
```

**Edit**
So I am doing something like this, I am using props just to initialize the state variable.

```
export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            email : this.props.user.email
        }
    },

    onFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    onTextFieldChange(event){

        switch (event.target.name) {
            case "email":
                this.setState({
                    email:event.target.value
                });
                break;
        }

    },

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.user.email);
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h3 className="panel-title text-center"><strong>Sign in with Existing Account</strong></h3>
                </div>
                <form className="form-horizontal" id="frmSignIn" role="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="col-xs-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div className="col-xs-8">
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" className="form-control"
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChange={this.onTextFieldChange}
                                    placeholder="example@domain.com"
                                    required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="col-xs-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div className="col-xs-8">
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                required/>
                                <label id="signin-error" className="error"> </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-footer">
                        <label className="col-xs-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div className="col-xs-8">
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="SignIn"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Note that props in `getInitialState` is an anti-pattern https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for the comment, can you see the edit? I am doing what fb says, but I get nothing in the input field, though the console log displays value correclty

Comment: You still didn't explain how it's being called, that's the place that would set the props, you probably aren't setting default props. And if you're copying the value from a prop to a state, you should not be using `this.props.user.email`, but `this.state.user.email`

Comment: Try `console.log`ging `this.props` in `getInitialState` and the next props in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Then you will see when and how your component receives the mentioned property value

Answer (score 0):

The component receives the initial properties immediately on instantiation. Actually it is the first argument of the constructor:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    // do something with props
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    // properties changed   
  }
}
```

In your case my best guess is that the parent component does not yet have your property ready. You can track the passed property by observing them in the constructor and in a `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function.

Comment: It is ready in `getInitialState()`, [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) shows it and it works fine. Note that the page says you shouldn't do it

Comment: When you are using ES6 classes, getInitialState doesn't exist. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Answer (score 0):

Meteor synchronises user data just like any other collection with the server. It means that initially `Meteor.user()` will return undefined, and your component doesn't receive the prop. Later when the user document is updated, your component's props are updated, too. You can catch this event by implementing `function componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {...}`.